# how to apply restriction to mysql users on usage of mysqldump

Tags: sql, database, linux, mysql

Hi i have requirement to create a database from which no data goes outside not in csv format or as a dump file.

If mysql crashes the data should be gone but no recovery should exist..

It may looks like stupid idea to implement but clients requirement is like that only..

So any one help me how to restrict **mysqlbump** client program and **INTO OUTFILE** commands for all users except root user. Other users will have **select insert update delete and etc database leve privileges but not global level privileges..**

Can any one help me on this ?

Comment: Are you talking about access control? Or do you mean the data shouldn't be saved in the first place? The `MEMORY` engine is good for when you want the data *gone*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you looking for, But if you have ssh access to server, I propose to use filesystem backup or some useful tools like  [innobackupex](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) instead of mysqldump.
For big data mysqldump isn't good solution.

Answer (score 0):

u must restrict every new mysql user to Select_priv, Lock_tables_priv, file,alter, crete tmp table , execute,create table . so the user cant do any things. even in mysqldump , they cant get export. use mysql.user table.  or use some tools like navicat .

Comment: Please use full words when providing answers here. When you're texting people you can do whatever you want, but these answers serve as a reference for others and will be around for a long time. The small amount of effort required to turn this into a response that's easy to read is not overwhelming, I hope.

Comment: OK, as u say , I'll do my best. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. From the perspective of the MySQL server, `mysqldump` is just another client that runs a lot of `SELECT` statements. What it happens to do with them (generate a dump file) is not something that the server can control.

For what it's worth, this sounds like an **incredibly** stupid idea, as it means that there will be no way to restore your client's data from backups if a disaster occurs (e.g, a hard drive fails, MySQL crashes and corrupts tables, someone accidentally deletes a bunch of data, etc). The smartest thing to do here will be to tell the client that you can't do it - anything else is setting yourself up for failure.